# Combine multiple awk functions

Tags: bash, shell, awk, grep

I'm very new to awk, I'm trying to do the following in an environment that doesn't support `grep -P` and doesn't have Perl installed either.

Given I have a list of env variables starting with a prefix, I want to generate an argument list based on those variables, without using the prefix.

So, for example, if I have

```bsh
PREFIX_VARIABLE_1=100
PREFIX_VARIABLE_2=500
```

I'd like to generate

```bsh
 --set service.VARIABLE_1=100 --set service.VARIABLE_2=500
```

I've came up with

```bsh
 env | awk 'match($0, /PREFIX_.*/) { substr($0, RSTART+8, RLENGTH) ; split($0, parts, "=") ; printf "--set service.%s=%s ", parts[1], parts[2] }'
```

but this doesn't strip the prefix, `substr` is not being used  I guess

With `grep -P` I can do it:

```bsh
 env | grep -oP '(?<=PREFIX_)(.*)' | awk 'split($0, parts, "=") { printf "--set service.%s=%s ", parts[1], parts[2] }'
```

Any idea how to chain/pipe multiple awk functions properly? Thanks

Comment: For `gawk` using option `--lint` is a good idea while developing, BTW.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code, with newlines for readability

```bsh
env | awk '
    match($0, /PREFIX_.*/) {
        substr($0, RSTART+8, RLENGTH) 
        split($0, parts, "=") 
        printf "--set service.%s=%s ", parts[1], parts[2]
    }
'
```

`substr` works just fine. You're not doing anything with the return value. substr by itself does not modify $0.

First, I'd recommend making the regex more specific, so that it finds `PREFIX_VAR=something` and not `some_other_var=$PREFIX_VAR`

Then, since you know what PREFIX is, I'd suggest you don't need to use RSTART etc.

Last, use `=` as the field separator to make it easier to work with the varname.

```bsh
env | awk -F= '$1 ~ /^PREFIX_/ {printf "--set service.%s=%s ", substr($1,8), $2}'
```

---

This code, like yours, will not properly handle the variable value containing an equal sign. To join fields 2..NF in awk is a bit of a hassle:

```bsh
env | awk '
    function join (fstart, fend, separator,      i, result) {
        for (i = fstart; i <= fend; i++) 
            result = result $i (i == fend ? "" : separator)
        return result
    }
    $1 ~ /^PREFIX_/ {
        var = substr($1, 8)
        value = join(2, NF, "=")
        printf "--set service.%s=%s ", var value
    }
'
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `cat file` in place of your `env` command:

```bsh
$ cat file | awk 'sub(/^PREFIX_/,"--set service."){out=out sep $0; sep=OFS} END{print out}'

--set service.VARIABLE_1=100 --set service.VARIABLE_2=500
```

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to do it without using `awk`. Just demonstrating another way

```
 while read -r env
   do 
     [[ $env == *PREFIX_* ]] && envs+=("--set service.${env#*_}")
   done < <(env)       
 printf '%s ' "${envs[@]}"
```

So here you read each line that has `PREFIX_` in it and append it to an array variable by using `+=`. The `${env#*_}`  makes sure that i.e:

```
PREFIX_VARIABLE_1=100
```

becomes

```
VARIABLE_1=100
```

See [String Manupulations](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100) for more.